# Create a SQL table to import (and convert) .CSV containing MySQL tstamp

Tags: mysql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I just don't seem to get a solution for my problem! I need to import this into SQL Server.

The 2nd column (and a few more) from a .CSV MySQL export contains the tstamp field, which I need converted.
I created the table, but the bulk import did not work. Got the following error message
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (tstamp).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 1 (tstamp).

Herewith the code.

```
-- Recreate the table
CREATE TABLE [Majestic].[dbo].hdiyouth
(tstamp datetime NOT NULL
)
GO

-- Bulk insert the data from csv file
-- Ensure the file(s) is/are closed! 
BULK
INSERT [Majestic].[dbo].hdiyouth
FROM 'C:\Path\CSV\hdiyouth.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Comment: Herewith a sample
>id;"tstamp";"tstamp_updated";"reg_id"
>24173;"0";"0";"1272167
>24175;"1319210236";"0";"1272167"
>24177;"0";"0";"1272173"
>24179;"1319210739";"0";"1272173";
>24181;"0";"0";"1272175";

Comment: I believe datetime accepts date and time in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format, try declaring tstamp field an integer or timestamp

Comment: I'm working within SQL. Timestamp is only allowed once (and is also used for something else) while int also did not want to work

Comment: then I fear that I wouldn't be much more of a help here, sorry and good luck

Comment: Thanks anyway - I'll ensure my tags and description is better going forward

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out LOAD DATA: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

A bit down there is an example of how to convert a column before inserting:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/bit_test.txt'
    -> INTO TABLE bit_test (@var1) SET b= CAST(@var1 AS UNSIGNED);
```

Comment: Hi, 

I don't think I mentioned it, but I would like to import it into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

how about creating a SSIS package to do that?

This [link](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/import-csv-flat-file-into-sql-server-using-ssis-integration-services.aspx) may help you

Comment: Is this available in the free version of SQL 2005? Perhaps in free version of 2008?

I'm thinking that the BIDS module is only available in the full version?

Comment: If you have installed SQL 2005 express edition and want to install BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio) then go to here http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19413

Comment: Found this-reinstalling SQL.

Probably nobody will see this new comment on an old post, but maybe it'll help somebody. Make sure when you install the core SQL Server components that you don't install any of the Client Components. That way when you install the Toolkit afterward you can tell it to install all components and you should get a clean install. I learned this by installing SQL Server 2005 Express with SP2 including Client Components, then went to install BIDS but it couldn't overwrite the already installed Client Components since they were a newer version. – Yohan P Jul 20 '11 at 2:31

Comment: Also tried c:\program files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\dtswizard.exe but it still works with old Excel and I have 600 columns in total!!
Out of ideas from my side!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you have the value "0" in the tstamp and tstamp_updated columns, which are of datatype timestamp, right?

MySQL supports NULL values in timestamp columns, also represented by '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. SQL Server does not support this. Don't get me wrong, it supports NULL value in timestamp columns, but not the '0' of MySQL. The easiest way to solve this may be using SSIS like Diego suggested. I personally solved this issue by converting MySQL NULL values to '1970-01-01', which is the minimum value for timestamp columns.